# How can I set up VS Code to save files using shift ZZ?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04, hotkeys

How can I set up VS Code to save files using `esc shift ZZ`?  I have the vim extension which works well.  I can use vim keystrokes for just about everything.  But I can't save my file with `esc shift ZZ`.  I have to use `Ctrl S`.  :(   Can I just remap a hot key?  I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You can, you'll want to look into how to create / map "chords" - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-rules

Comment: Is this safe?  I wonder why the vim extension didn't add this themselves?  It makes me think there's a problem.  Thank you, however.  I will certainly learn about creating map chords.  :)

Answer (score 0):

This works.  This is my whole settings.json file.  Ctrl shift P brings up the command palette.  Ttpe in "setting" and select settings.json.

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python",
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Hack Nerd Font",
    "kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Andromeda Colorizer",
    "git.suggestSmartCommit": true,
    "editor.fontSize": 18,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": ["Z", "Z"],
            "commands": [
                ":w"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true
}
```

add this section:

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": ["Z", "Z"],
            "commands": [
                ":w"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

:w is for write.  :wq will write and save.  I chose :w because I want to save without closing the file.

Cheers all!